# mudar o nome do botão com javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um player, e não posso usar ícones, tenho que fazer tudo em uma página só, não estou conseguindo mudar o texto do botão para `Pause` quando o áudio esta sendo executado e `Play` quando o áudio está pausado, oque eu tentei foi isso mais não deu certo `videoElement.pause();

```
            playButton.querySelector('span').className = "btPlay".innerHTML("Pause");`
` videoElement.play();
            playButton.querySelector('span').className = "btPause".innerHTML("Pause");`
```

O que estou fazendo de errado ? aqui está o `js` completo e a parte do `html` que se refere aos botão

quando eu atualizo a página ele toca normalmente, ai eu aperto `pause` ele pausea normalmente, e mostra o botão de `play` só que ai eu aperto `play` ele não mostra o botão de `pause` e aparece esses dois erros [image: linhas dos erros][image: nome do erro]

```
    var player, drag;
var audioElement, playButton, slider, audioButton, icoAudio;
function selectPlayer(elem){
    if( player != elem ){ 
        player = elem;
    }
    audioElement   = player.querySelector('audio'); //Objeto do player
    playButton     = player.querySelector('.play'); //Botão play e pause
    slider         = player.querySelector('.slider'); 
    sliderVol      = slider.querySelector('.bar');
    audioButton    = player.querySelector('.audio');
    //Ações do mouse
    playButton.addEventListener('click', playAudio);
    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', showVolume);
    sliderVol.addEventListener('mousemove', showVolume);
    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
    sliderVol.addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
    sliderVol.querySelector('span').addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', startDrag);
    audioButton.addEventListener('click', mute);
}
function startDrag(event){
    if(event.type == "mousedown"){
        drag = true;
    }else{
        drag = false;
    }
}
function showVolume(event){
    if(drag){
        var w = slider.clientWidth;
        var x = (event.clientX) - slider.offsetLeft;
        var pctVol = x/w;

        if(pctVol >1 ){
            sliderVol.style.width = 100+"%";
            audioElement.volume = 1;
        }else if( pctVol < 0 ){
            sliderVol.style.width = 0+"%";
            audioElement.volume = 0;
        }else{
            sliderVol.style.width = (x/w) * 100+"%";
            audioElement.volume = pctVol;
        }
        if(pctVol<=0){
            audioButton.querySelector('span').className = 'ion-volume-mute';
        }else if(pctVol>0 && pctVol<=0.6){
            audioButton.querySelector('span').className = 'ion-volume-low';
        }else{
            audioButton.querySelector('span').className = 'ion-volume-medium';
        }
    }
}
function mute(){
    if(!audioElement.muted){
        audioElement.muted = true;
        audioElement.volume = 0;
        sliderVol.style.width = 0+"%";
        audioButton.querySelector('span').className = 'ion-volume-mute';
    }else{
        audioElement.muted = false;
        audioElement.querySelector('span').className = 'ion-volume-medium';
        audioElement.volume = 0.9;
        sliderVol.style.width = 90+"%";
    }
}
function playAudio(){
    // Verifica se a música foi iniciada
    if(audioElement.played.length != 0){
        // Verifica se a música foi pausada
        if(audioElement.played.start(0)==0 && !audioElement.paused){
            audioElement.pause(); // Pausa a música
            playButton.querySelector('span').className = "btPlay"; // Muda a imagem do botão pause para o play
            playButton.innerHTML = "<img src='http://i.cubeupload.com/Ad7lc8.png' width='25' height='25' alt='Reproduzir' title='Reproduzir'/>";
        }else{
            audioElement.play();
            playButton.querySelector('span').className = "btPause"; // Muda a imagem do botão play para pause
            playbutton.innerHTML = "<img src='http://i.cubeupload.com/SPRXTQ.png' width='25' height='25' alt='Pausar' title='Pausar'>";
        }
    }else{
        audioElement.play(); //Se não estiver pausada ela toca automaticamente
        playButton.querySelector('span').className = "btPause"; // Muda o icone do botão play para pause
        playButton.innerHTML = "<img src='http://i.cubeupload.com/SPRXTQ.png' width='25' height='25' alt='Pausar' title='Pausar'>";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Botão de play e pause -->
            <div class="control left play">
                <!-- btPause -->
                <!-- Como padrão a imagem que apresenta no player é de pausar -->
                <span class="btPause"><img src='http://i.cubeupload.com/SPRXTQ.png' width='25' height='25' alt='Pausar' title='Pausar'></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Você precisa super editar essa postagem, ta muito bagunçada..

Comment: foi o melhor q consegui, espera, alguém ja edita, só nao entende o porque do voto negativo se estou aqui pra aprender, e não estou pedindo nada pronto

Comment: É que não adianta só jogar o código na pergunta. Vc precisa ser específico, mostrar onde as coisas acontecem, explicar, mostrar de forma clara e precisa. Onde acontece o quê, botar setas, prints de tela, gravar um vídeo etc.. (não, sacanagem rs)... fiz a piada só pra vc ver que tem que mostrar o problema de forma mais clara.

Comment: Tipo: _Eu tenho esse botão aqui (mostra o código) e ao clicar nele chama essa função (código)... quero que ao clicar mude o texto de X para Y... o botão começa com o texto X...._

Comment: @dvd rsrsrs editei a pergunta, fiz o exemplo do amigo ali em baixo e funcionou, só que está dando um erro, não sei porque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seu problema seja estar usando o `querySelector()` de forma errada.
Uma vez que você quer buscar um elemento específico, é mais fácil usar a classe dele ou o `id`, neste caso, se você tem certeza que o audio está tocando, você sabe qual a classe que o ícone tem, se é `.btPlay` ou `.btPause`, tendo isso, facilita a busca pelo elemento.

abaixo deixo um exemplo prático e funcional que você pode adotar e utilizar. Para o o exemplo, fiz pequenas alterações e deixei o código bem limpo, agora é só pegar a lógica e a sintaxe e adicionar ao seu código.

Veja que eu seleciono o botão de play usando `document.querySelect(".ClasseDoBotao")`, se audio está tocando, a classe dele é `btPause`(pq vai pausar), senão é `btPlay`. Feito isso, é só alterar o elemento.

O erro que você está recebendo na sua imagem, é que o `querySelector` não está achando o elemento na tela, pois você está procurando ele errado usando `playButton.querySelector` o JS não sabe o que é playButton neste caso.

```js
var audioTocando = true;
document.querySelector('.control').onclick = function(){
  if(audioTocando){
        audioTocando = false;
        var playButton = document.querySelector('.btPause');
        playButton.className = "btPlay";
        playButton.innerHTML = "<img src='http://i.cubeupload.com/Ad7lc8.png' width='25' height='25' alt='Reproduzir' title='Reproduzir'/>";
  } else {
        audioTocando = true;
        var playButton = document.querySelector('.btPlay')
        playButton.className = "btPause";
        playButton.innerHTML = "<img src='http://i.cubeupload.com/SPRXTQ.png' width='25' height='25' alt='Pausar' title='Pausar'>";
  }
}
```

```css
.btPause{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btPlay{
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="control left play">
    <span class="btPause">Click</span>
</div>
```

Comment: eita mano vcoê é zika, deu certinho valeu

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, nunca cheguei a usar esse método `querySelector`, normalmente eu uso `document.getElementById` ou `document.getElementsByClassName` quando eu quero modificar elementos html.

Por exemplo, esse caso expecifico seria resolvido assim:

```
const playButton = document.getElementsByClassName("btPlay");
playButton.innerHTML = 'Pause'
```

Até onde eu saiba também, faz parte das melhores práticas usar Ids para esses tipos de caso onde só vai ser modificado um elemento isolado

Usando Id ficaria assim:

**JavaScript**

```
const playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
playButton.innerHTML = 'Pause'
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="control left play">
    <!-- btPause -->
    <div class="btPlay" id="playButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelector` pode selecionar qualquer coisa, incluindo `id`, tag, classe, `name`... é a mesma coisa que `document.getElementBy...` só que ele sempre vai retornar apenas o primeiro elemento encontrado, exceto se usar `querySelectorAll`...

Comment: @CalvinNunes procurando um pouco na internet parece que `querySelector` sempre pega um estado estatico do elemento, enquanto `getElementBy...` vai retornar um objeto 'live' do elemento, ou seja, vai estar sempre atualizado. Acredito que na maioria dos casos um objeto live vai ser sempre melhor.